# How to make Gurobi solve huge LP/IP model with only using A,b,c matrices?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, gurobi

I work on the scaling of MIP. I have scaled the A,b,c matrices of the huge original model. These matrices have more than 25000 rows and columns. I need to make Gurobi solve the scaled model. Normally, I use the .lp file and give it to the Gurobi but in this case, I only have three scaled matrices and not the model itself in a .lp file.

Matrices are received as the output of a C++ program and could be transferred anywhere.

How can I solve LP/IP using A,b,c matrices only?

Same question, in other words, how can I place back scaled matrices to the .lp file again?

Comment: This question is just too broad. Try to code it first.

Comment: Use the C++ API for Gurobi to rebuild the model using the new matrices, then export it if necessary to a file.

Comment: You could write the LP file by hand. Right? It would cumbersome though. So you could just write C++ code that does it.

Comment: @prubin Is there any function in the C++ API to rebuild the model using matrices?

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK I could write code to create an LP file but then it would be specific to that LP file, right? I looking for something to create a .lp file from matrices that I have scaled and does that for different.lp file inputs

Comment: @Brannon I will code, but first, I would like to know what to code, what should be the approach? Is there any C++ API functions that help me to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Gurobi user. CPLEX provides such functionality, so I would bet Gurobi does as well.

Comment: @prubin Is there any specific function/package in CPLEX that does that? Is there any links/sources you can recommend that I can get more info about it?

Comment: Related (not a dupe): [How to create A, b and c matrices from very large .lp file?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/7913/491)

Comment: In the Java API for CPLEX, there's an interface named `IloLPMatrix` with methods that let you add rows or columns. The C++ API has the same capability (possibly with a different name).

Answer (score 3):

You are spamming the ORExchange and Stackoverflow forums with several very related questions without providing links between them. This is bad practice and disrespectful of the time of other community members trying to answer your questions.

- [How to create A, b and c matrices from very large .lp file?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/how-to-create-a-b-and-c-matrices-from-very-large-lp-file)
- [How to make CLion read .lp file and make Gurobi solve that file within CLion?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7856/how-to-make-clion-read-lp-file-and-make-gurobi-solve-that-file-within-clion)
- [SO: How to make CLion read .lp file and make Gurobi solve that file within CLion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220356/how-to-make-clion-read-lp-file-and-make-gurobi-solve-that-file-within-clion/71223347#71223347)
- [SO: How to find row [i] and column [j] of Sparse Matrix/Vector A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326172/how-to-find-row-i-and-column-j-of-sparse-matrix-vector-a)
- [Gurobi Community: How to make CLion read .lp file and make Gurobi solve that file within CLion?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4460822390289-How-to-make-CLion-read-lp-file-and-make-Gurobi-solve-that-file-within-CLion-)

Math programming is usually taught using matrices but in code, the common approach (at least for linear problems) is to use a constraint-based way. You should scale the matrix coefficients column-wise or row-wise by traversing the constraints (rows) and variables (columns) of your problem. It is counterproductive and way more difficult to extract the full matrix and then feed the data back into the solver. And by the way: 25k rows and columns is anything from huge.

In Gurobi's [Guidelines for Numerical Issues](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/guidelines_for_numerical_i.html), there is an example that demonstrates how you can apply scaling factors to an existing problem: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/_code_for_the_experiment_w.html

Comment: Firstly, I do not think all these questions are related. It does not make sense to link them. Secondly,I would like to ask some questions on different websites. It is so useful since they are for different people from different backgrounds, and I would like to learn their approach. I do not think I did anything disrespectful, you can click the links and open and see all my answers/comments. Thirdly, please look for the meaning of spam, asking questions are anything but spam. Lastly, I will keep asking questions and if you do not like my questions please do not enter and answer/comment on them.